# How do I return my string inside an if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, return

```
public static String  mixColors1(String x, String y)
{
    String red="red";
    String yellow="yellow";
    String blue="blue";
    String color = null;//this line... is an issue
    if(red == x && yellow == y || red == y && yellow == x)//if red&yellow selected
        color = "orange";//return orange

    else if(red == x && blue == y || red == y && blue == x)//if red&blue selected
        color = "purple";//return purple

    else if(yellow == x && blue == y || yellow == y && blue == x)//if blue&yellow selected
        color = "green";//return green

    return color;
}
```

Comment: First off, never compare Strings with `==`. Use the `equals(...)` method.

Comment: What's wrong with this code? Why put the returns inside the if statement?

Comment: can you please give me an example of the equals(..) please?

Comment: @Weiner I gave sample code below. You will get null if one of the colors is neither red, blue nor yellow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong with setting the `color` inside the `if`s and `return`ing it at the end, but here is what you wanted:

Replace your `if...else` ladder with the following:

```
if(red.equals(x) && yellow.equals(y) || red.equals(y) && yellow.equals(x))//if red&yellow selected
    return "orange";
else if(red.equals(x) && blue.equals(y) || red.equals(y) && blue.equals(x))//if red&blue selected
    return "purple";
else if(yellow.equals(x) && blue.equals(y) || yellow.equals(y) && blue.equals(x))//if blue&yellow selected
    return "green";
else
    return null;  // default value, if neither orange nor purple nor green
```

This simply switches out the setting of `color` with a `return` statement. (Returning *inside* the `if` statements like the original question asked.)

This also shows how to properly use the `.equals()` method like you asked in the comment.

Comment: @I.C.Weiner You can totally have multiple `return`s! The first one that the method encounters will be the one that breaks it out of the method, however. So you can *have* multiple `return`s, but only one will be *executed*.

Comment: @I.C.Weiner No problem! I'm glad I helped (make sure to accept if I did)!

Answer (score 0):

as per you request.. here is the code..

```
 public static String  mixColors1(String x, String y)
    {
        String red="red";
        String yellow="yellow";
        String blue="blue";
        if(red.equals(x) && yellow.equals(y) || red.equals(y) && yellow.equals(x))//if red&yellow selected
            return "orange";//return orange

        else if(red.equals(x) && blue.equals(y) || red.equals(y) && blue.equals(x))//if red&blue selected
            return "purple";//return purple

        else if(yellow.equals(x) && blue.equals(y) || yellow.equals(y) && blue.equals(x))//if blue&yellow selected
            return "green";//return green
        else
        return null;            //if color won't match it will return null

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question

Comment: you are right. I gave him explanation of where his logic is wrong or assumptions or wrong. so that he can learn it from mistakes.

Comment: But you still didn't make it return from inside the ifs.

Comment: we are returning only one statement based on the if else condition. please have a look at java documentation for more details..

Comment: @RamPrakash Those `if`s are now an exact copy of my answer :(

Comment: @RamPrakash I tend to have that effect. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {
    public static String remarkStudent(int score) {
        // Write your code here
        if ((score>75)&& (score<=100)) {
            return "Distinction";
        } else if ((score>50)&& (score<=75)) {
         return "Average";
        } else if ((score>30)&& (score<=50)) {
            return  "Below Average";
        } else{
            return null ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).